# Rails rspec returns no examples found when spec/..._spec.rb file exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I am trying to setup our Rails project to use rspec. But I am getting 'No examples found' when I run rspec. How can I get rspec to run the example(s)?

I am just using the command `rspec` with any options or settings.

Rails: 6.0.3.4
Ruby: 2.7.2

My spec file is in the `spec/requests` folder and has the following content

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "Posts", type: :request do

  describe "GET /index unauthenticated" do
    it "returns http 403" do
      get "/posts"
      expect(response).to have_http_status(403)
    end
  end

end
```

My 'spec_helper.rb' is

```
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'byebug'

# This file was generated by the `rails generate rspec:install` command. Conventionally, all
# specs live under a `spec` directory, which RSpec adds to the `$LOAD_PATH`.
# The generated `.rspec` file contains `--require spec_helper` which will cause
# this file to always be loaded, without a need to explicitly require it in any
# files.
#
# Given that it is always loaded, you are encouraged to keep this file as
# light-weight as possible. Requiring heavyweight dependencies from this file
# will add to the boot time of your test suite on EVERY test run, even for an
# individual file that may not need all of that loaded. Instead, consider making
# a separate helper file that requires the additional dependencies and performs
# the additional setup, and require it from the spec files that actually need
# it.
#
# See http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # rspec-expectations config goes here. You can use an alternate
  # assertion/expectation library such as wrong or the stdlib/minitest
  # assertions if you prefer.
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    # This option will default to `true` in RSpec 4. It makes the `description`
    # and `failure_message` of custom matchers include text for helper methods
    # defined using `chain`, e.g.:
    #     be_bigger_than(2).and_smaller_than(4).description
    #     # => "be bigger than 2 and smaller than 4"
    # ...rather than:
    #     # => "be bigger than 2"
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  # rspec-mocks config goes here. You can use an alternate test double
  # library (such as bogus or mocha) by changing the `mock_with` option here.
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    # Prevents you from mocking or stubbing a method that does not exist on
    # a real object. This is generally recommended, and will default to
    # `true` in RSpec 4.
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  # This option will default to `:apply_to_host_groups` in RSpec 4 (and will
  # have no way to turn it off -- the option exists only for backwards
  # compatibility in RSpec 3). It causes shared context metadata to be
  # inherited by the metadata hash of host groups and examples, rather than
  # triggering implicit auto-inclusion in groups with matching metadata.
  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups

# The settings below are suggested to provide a good initial experience
# with RSpec, but feel free to customize to your heart's content.
=begin
  # This allows you to limit a spec run to individual examples or groups
  # you care about by tagging them with `:focus` metadata. When nothing
  # is tagged with `:focus`, all examples get run. RSpec also provides
  # aliases for `it`, `describe`, and `context` that include `:focus`
  # metadata: `fit`, `fdescribe` and `fcontext`, respectively.
  config.filter_run_when_matching :focus

  # Allows RSpec to persist some state between runs in order to support
  # the `--only-failures` and `--next-failure` CLI options. We recommend
  # you configure your source control system to ignore this file.
  config.example_status_persistence_file_path = "spec/examples.txt"

  # Limits the available syntax to the non-monkey patched syntax that is
  # recommended. For more details, see:
  #   - http://rspec.info/blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax/
  #   - http://www.teaisaweso.me/blog/2013/05/27/rspecs-new-message-expectation-syntax/
  #   - http://rspec.info/blog/2014/05/notable-changes-in-rspec-3/#zero-monkey-patching-mode
  config.disable_monkey_patching!

  # Many RSpec users commonly either run the entire suite or an individual
  # file, and it's useful to allow more verbose output when running an
  # individual spec file.
  if config.files_to_run.one?
    # Use the documentation formatter for detailed output,
    # unless a formatter has already been configured
    # (e.g. via a command-line flag).
    config.default_formatter = "doc"
  end

  # Print the 10 slowest examples and example groups at the
  # end of the spec run, to help surface which specs are running
  # particularly slow.
  config.profile_examples = 10

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = :random

  # Seed global randomization in this process using the `--seed` CLI option.
  # Setting this allows you to use `--seed` to deterministically reproduce
  # test failures related to randomization by passing the same `--seed` value
  # as the one that triggered the failure.
  Kernel.srand config.seed
=end

  config.expect_with :rspec do |c|
    c.syntax = :expect
  end
end

Dir["./spec/support/**/*.rb"].each {|f| require f}
```

My 'rails_helper.rb' file is

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
require 'spec_helper'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)
# Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?

require 'rspec/rails'

require 'database_cleaner/active_record'

require 'capybara/rspec'

require "shoulda/matchers"

Dir[Rails.root.join('spec', 'support', '**', '*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

# Add additional requires below this line. Rails is not loaded until this point!

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc, in
# spec/support/ and its subdirectories. Files matching `spec/**/*_spec.rb` are
# run as spec files by default. This means that files in spec/support that end
# in _spec.rb will both be required and run as specs, causing the specs to be
# run twice. It is recommended that you do not name files matching this glob to
# end with _spec.rb. You can configure this pattern with the --pattern
# option on the command line or in ~/.rspec, .rspec or `.rspec-local`.
#
# The following line is provided for convenience purposes. It has the downside
# of increasing the boot-up time by auto-requiring all files in the support
# directory. Alternatively, in the individual `*_spec.rb` files, manually
# require only the support files necessary.
#
# Dir[Rails.root.join('spec', 'support', '**', '*.rb')].sort.each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migrations and applies them before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove these lines.
begin
  ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
rescue ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError => e
  puts e.to_s.strip
  exit 1
end
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods

  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller

  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!

  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller

  config.extend ControllerMacros, type: :controller

  config.include RequestSpecHelper, type: :request

  config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods

end


Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    with.test_framework :rspec

    with.library :active_record
    with.library :active_model
    with.library :action_controller
    with.library :rails
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.around(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
      example.run
    end
  end

end
```

And my '.rspec' file is

```
--require spec_helper
```

I've pushed the complete project code to https://github.com/marksack/rspec-test

EDIT: I did some debugging by stepping through the rspec core code. At some points in the code, I can that it has found the spec files. But it seems to break for some reason when it gets to the point of loading them - perhaps in the `load_file_handling_errors` method. The invocation of that method passes in the correct file and I don't see any exceptions though.

Comment: how are you running your tests? share the command or something else

Comment: @dev-cc Added a comment to indicate the command I am using. It is just rspec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have a cache configuration issue with `stimulus_reflex` gem when you run the `rspec` command:

> Stimulus Reflex requires caching to be enabled. Caching allows the
> session to be modified during ActionCable requests. To enable caching
> in development, run:
> rails dev:cache
>
> If you know what you are doing and you want to start the application
> anyway, you can create a StimulusReflex initializer with the command:
>
> bundle exec rails generate stimulus_reflex:config
>
> Then open your initializer at
>
> <RAILS_ROOT>/config/initializers/stimulus_reflex.rb
>
> and then add the following directive:
>
> StimulusReflex.configure do |config|
> config.on_failed_sanity_checks = :warn   end
>
> No examples found.

Try replacing this part of **config/environments/test.rb**:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
config.cache_store = :null_store
```

with:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.cache_store = :memory_store
```

Then it should work as expected